# How do I declare a function that can perform an assignment operation? (C++)

Tags: c++, function, assignment-operator

I am trying to create a function similar to the `at()` function in `std::vector`. I know how to overload the operator for `=` but this is not what I am after. I have a matrix object and I am looking to perform an operation along the lines of overwriting a column vector of the matrix, i.e.

```
int rowNumber = 3; int columnNumber = 3;
Matrix myMatrix(rowNumber, columnNumber);
Vector myColumnVector(rowNumber);
myMatrix.col(2) = myColumnVector;
```

where `col()` is the assignment function. How do I declare this function?

Comment: Have a `Matrix::col()` function returning a reference to the underlying datatype. Add some more information about how exactly your `Matrix` class is defined to receive some concise answers here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use some proxy:

```
struct Matrix;

struct ColWrapper
{
    Matrix* mMatrix;
    int mIndex;

    ColWrapper& operator =(const std::vector<double>& d);
};

struct RowWrapper
{
    Matrix* mMatrix;
    int mIndex;

    RowWrapper& operator =(const std::vector<double>& d);
};

struct Matrix
{
    std::vector<double> mData;
    int mRow;

    Matrix(int row, int column) : mData(row * colunmn), mRow(row) {}


    ColWrapper col(int index) { return {this, index}; }
    RowWrapper row(int index) { return {this, index}; }
};

ColWrapper& ColWrapper::operator =(const std::vector<double>& ds)
{
    auto index = mIndex * mMatrix->mRow;

    for (auto d : ds) {
        mMatrix->mData[index] = d;
        index += 1;
    }
    return *this;
}

RowWrapper& RowWrapper::operator =(const std::vector<double>& ds)
{
    auto index = mIndex;

    for (auto d : ds) {
        mMatrix->mData[index] = d;
        index += mMatrix->mRow;
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`col()` is not the assignment function.

`operator=()` is the assignment function.

`col()` is the function that evaluates to the thing you will be assigning to. In this case, a reference to a `Vector` (i.e. `Vector&`) will do the job.